# How to make those old-school GUIs (like the debian/arch installer)

Tags: scripting, distributions, gui

I've been doing a lot of installs lately, and when possible I usually opt for the text install from the Live CD's GRUB menu. Most installers looks like this:

[image]

I always thought these GUIs (if you can call them as such) were really awesome and lightweight. Seeing as a lot of applications/distros use them, it must be a shared library or something right? Is there a way I can make stuff like this?

Comment: It should be noted that most of the sysinstallers for linux & bsd have horrible user interface presentation using curses regarding the OK and Cancel buttons: it's rarely clear when the user has highlighted them.  When implementing with curses it's best not to use those installers as a design example; go back to review those old DOS programs instead, like Lotus 123, for how good ANSI graphics GUIs should work in terms of UI.  It's something like: [Ok] is lightly colored but not highlighted, until selected by the user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/).

Comment: Reading back I ask myself what exactly "hitting the money means"... I guess I was just excited.

Comment: @MaxMackie: Now *that* follow-up question would be better suited for http://english.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Answer (score 14):

I don't know about Arch and Debian, but oftentimes those GUIs are made with `dialog(1)`, which takes a bunch of command-line arguments and then renders a dialog with `ncurses`. For examples, the Linux kernel menuconfig looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of menuconfig]

An example `dialog` usage is:

```
$ dialog --title "Hello" --infobox "Hello there Unix and Linux Stack Exchange" 20 100
```

Which results in:

[image: Screenshot of dialog(1)]

Comment: This is pure awesome, so dialog uses ncurses to draw to the terminal? Couldn't be easier than that. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

At a higher level, the ones that look *exactly like that* generally use something like [newt/whiptail](https://fedorahosted.org/newt/) or [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/). That particular one looks like it's newt/whiptail, since dialog tends to draw a frame around controls like that listbox. For another example, the linux kernel config uses a cut-down custom version of dialog (without extra features it doesn't use, and I would imagine the yes/no/module checkbox is a custom feature)